# Describe the preimage of the set

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I've been stumped on this problem for a while now, unable to find many resources to help me understand how to describe a preimage of a set given a function like this one.

Let $f$: $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ be the function defined by *f(n)* = the last digit of *n*. For example, $f(-234)=4$

Describe the premiere of the set {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}

Comment: Notice how all of those elements are multiples of 2. So your pre image is simply the set of integers divisible by 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply the set of all integers ending with the digit $0$, $2$, $4$, $6$ or $8$. This is precisely the set of all even integers, or $\{2k:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: Right, but how would that be described in some universal way using something like set notation?

Comment: It is the set $\left\{z\in\mathbb{Z}: 2\mid z\right\}$

Comment: Ah okay I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

notationwise:

if $n \in \{0,...,9\}$ then $f^{-1}(n)=\{\pm(10^k+n)\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ so (as explained by previous comments)
$$
f^{-1}(\{0,2,4,6,8\}) = 2\mathbb{Z}
$$